# What kind for authentication I should use in Google Blogger Data API for my facebook application

Tags: django, facebook, oauth-2.0, google-data-api

I am building a facebook application (using Django) in which I have to read data from blogs using Google Blogger Data API. The blog could be any public blog.

So, what kind of authentication/ authorization mechanism I should use in Google Blogger API for my application and how? I don't want a redirected Google log-in page to open in my app.

Google Console also provides API Key by which we can read public data but I am not sure if it is really a right choice for my app.

*I am currently using ClientLogin under development.*

I even got a weird idea of using ClientLogin even after the release to read data from my blog as it doesn't limit the number of requests/ day. Does that make my blog insecure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `OAuth Service protocols` or `Google API Access tokens` for pulling public data would do that job.